# 'property' object cannot be intepreted as an integer

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, oop

I discovered Python properties recently and I have been using it as a way to get 'read only' members, but now troubles arrive...

I have some 'read-only' numbers stored into properties inside a config class and I want to re-use those number in numpy/tensorflow, something a bit like:

```py
class MyConfig:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self._val = val

    @property
    def val(self):
        return self._val


conf = MyConfig(10)
np.ones(conf.val)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: expected sequence object with len >= 0 or a single integer
```

In my real code, the error is triggered by a `np.reshape` and the error message is a little different (`TypeError: 'property' object cannot be interpreted as integer`). I assume the cause for the error is the same as in this little example and only the error helper message differs.

Am I doing something wrong?
Can't properties be used in other functions for the values they embed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tested your snippet and there is no error from this. The issue might be somewhere else. Debug it [image]

Comment: You are right. The small example I tried was a little different, `_val` was a class member instead of an instance member, that triggered the first error. The second error was due to the fact that I had written `def fun(config=MyConfig):` instead of `def fun(config=MyConfig())`, i.e. I passed the class as a default value instead of an instance (supposing MyConfig has default parameters initialization). Sorry for the wrong post, I should have rewritten the code before posting. Should I just accept are modify my post in some ways to make it more sensible? Or remove it?

Comment: You can edit it if the problem persists, and rephrase the question or delete it and post another question with the exact details. It's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with petronella. Code executes as expected on my iPhone in Pythonista

```
>>> conf = MyConfig(10)
>>> type(conf.val)
<class 'int'>
>>> conf.val
10
>>> np.ones(conf.val)
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```